# Pandas Series apply lambda: NoneType found, but there are only str and list in the series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

EDIT: jezrael had the right answer for the question I asked below. Unfortunately for me, I asked the wrong question. As it turns out, the problem was that the lists of strings in the DataFrame column contained `None` elements, which is where the error was coming from. Please see the answer I have added for the code I used to fix this.

SECOND EDIT: jezrael has updated his answer to a way of doing what I did but more succinctly in a lambda expression.

---

I have a DataFrame, of which I select a column, upon which I call `apply`, to which I provide the parameter of a lambda expression, which is an `if` statement. I understand that at this point the column is treated as a Series.

The column is made of up strings and lists of strings, the latter of which I wish to convert to just plain strings by concatenating their elements and replacing that list with the resulting string, so that the FataFrame column is just strings.

Relevant code:

```
raw_data.address = raw_data.address.fillna('')
```

At this point I have looped through the entire address column and added all the types to a set - the only elements in that set are `str` and `list`.

```
raw_data.address.apply(lambda x: x if type(x) == str else ' '.join(x))
```

and

```
raw_data.address.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, str) else ' '.join(x))
```

do not work.

This is the error message in both cases:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-5e2dce775d20> in <module>
----> 1 raw_data.address.apply(lambda x: x if type(x) == str else ' '.join(x))

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3589             else:
   3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3592 
   3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-32-5e2dce775d20> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 raw_data.address.apply(lambda x: x if type(x) == str else ' '.join(x))

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. My understanding is that the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was that the lists in the DataFrame contained `None` elements themselves. To solve this, instead of using a lambda function in apply, I just wrote a normal function, that uses the inbuilt function `filter` to remove the `None`s in the lists:

```
def make_strings(thing):
    if isinstance(thing, list):
        return ' '.join(filter(None, thing))
    else:
        return str(thing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare list and remove `None` values:

```
raw_data = pd.DataFrame({'address':[['a', 'b', None], 'c']})
print (raw_data)
        address
0  [a, b, None]
1             c

raw_data.address = (raw_data.address
                            .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(filter(None, x)) 
                                             if isinstance(x, list)
                                             else x))
print (raw_data)
  address
0     a b
1       c
```

Comment: Sorry: those all run with out error, but I want to `join` the `list` (non `str`) elements, and _not_ `join` the `str` elements.